asp-action and asp-controller in innerHtml in js file
I need insert Html in Html document. I use innerHtml for this.
let newCardHTML = `
                    <div class="header">
                        <h4 class="card-counter">${currentCardNumber}</h4>
                        a class="button-bin btn" asp-action="DeleteCard" asp-controller="Cards" asp-route-cardId="currentCardNumber" ></a>                       
                    </div>`

I receive error Attribute DeleteCard is not allowed here.
I try
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteCard","Cards", new {cardId = 0})';
var linkHtml = '<a class = button-bin btn" href ="' + url+ '"></a>';
newCardHTML.querySelector('.header').innerHTML = linkHtml;

However this doesn't work and Local variable linkHtml is redundant.

An asp-* attribute is not standard HTML, but needs to be inside a cshtml file to be processed correctly and work

Okay, how can I replace these attributes for js file?

You couldn't directly use the Razor syntax with the asp.net core tag helper inside the js string, one solution is using the @Url.Action to generate the url and then put it inside the js.
More details, you could refer to below codes:
<div class="container">


</div>

@{
    var baseUrl = Url.Action("DeleteCard", "Cards", new { cardId = 0 });
}


@section Scripts{


    <script>
         
let currentCardNumber = 1; 

// Replace the '0' in the base URL with the actual card number
let deleteCardUrl = '@baseUrl'.replace('0', currentCardNumber);

let newCardHTML = `
    <div class="header">
        <h4 class="card-counter">${currentCardNumber}</h4>
        <a class="button-bin btn" href="${deleteCardUrl}"></a>                       
    </div>
`;

 
document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML += newCardHTML;
        </script>
}

Result:

